# What seems to be wrong with my automated Lettuce farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have a lettuce farm. It works and at the same time not work...

[image: Lettuce Farm]

I've hooked everything up and it is partially working. This is what I have observed:

1. The Planter is able to plant any modded seeds.
2. The Harvester only harvests ONLY Carrots and Potatoes.
3. The Harvester can't chop trees.
4. The Harvester seem to take about 2 minutes to realize that something is actually ready for harvest (tested with Carrots) before harvesting it.
5. The Planter seem to take about a minute to realize that a plot is empty (also tested with Carrots) before planting on/tilling it.

Also, all the machines are hooked up...

- The QDS (Quest Delivery System) is the block with a "Mushroom Cake" on it.
- The pipes contain sludge (not used currently) for the quest (which is finished).
- The Sludge Boiler is directly behind (from POV) the QDS.
- The Lava Generator (power source) is underneath the Sludge Boiler
- The Harvester is underneath the QDS (proper position)
- The Planter is under that tiny patch of water in the middle...
  And it is hooked to the Harvester with Itemducts and to the Lava Generator via Leadstone energy wiring stuff.
- All machines are powered with Leadstone energy wiring stuff.

So, basically:

1. Is there any way to make it work faster and be more responsive?
2. Is there anything wrong with the build/layout?
3. Why can't I harvest anything other than carrots and potatoes? (The only way to harvest is to do it by hand; right click/breaking)

---

If you want to hop into the world to see what's wrong, just contact me.. Or leave a comment.
*Modpack: FeedTheBeast - AgarianSkies v3.1.1 | Updated from V2.1.9 and the problem still persists.*

Comment: To speak on your harvester\planter taking 2 minutes to realize it must harvest, the larger the space the harvester services, the longer this wait time excists. See, the harvest checks each block individually in a linear sequence before starting over at 'block 1'. So if something in block 1 grows, and the harvester is checking block 2, it wont harvest block 1 until it starts the entire 'check for grown' sequence over.

Comment: Ok. I think I know what to do now... Downgrade from a Radius of 10 to 5... Also, can this process be sped up? (ie. From a 5-tick waiting period to say... 1-tick?)  
Do you know how to fix the mod not allowing the harvesting of seeded plants? (Anything that needs seeds ie. Not Carrot/Potato but Lettuce/Tomatoes/Wheat/Melon/Trees [of any sort])

Comment: Get a mod called Aroma1997 and another called Better chests, these two mods do the same as what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Jonco98, there is already JABBA with the Barrels that can store many things.. But my question is not about storage issues, it's about the MineFactory Reloaded Harvester and Planter not compatible with Pam's mod items... If you haven't realize: LETTUCE IS NOT A VANILLA CROP!

Comment: The two mods will plant/harvest and kind of plant, so in your case, lettuce. Plus its a lot more simple than this, all it uses is a chest with a water bucket in it

Comment: @Jonco98, BetterChests isn't in the modpack. http://ftbwiki.org/Agrarian_Skies for the list. So using new mods aren't an option... Plus that is trying to detour from the problem rather than to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit old, but the likely issue is that you don't have a secondary item output. If all you have is harvester->pipes->planter, and you can't send the lettuce heads anywhere, things jam up. The reason carrots/potatoes work is that the plant is the same as the seed, so it can just send everything to the planter.

You'll want a chest to output stuff to, making sure the planter still has priority for seeds.

Comment: How would I set it up though?

Comment: Basically, take the existing setup, connect one extra itemduct to the itemduct connected to the harvester, set the extra itemduct to dense mode, and connect it to a chest. Anything that can go to the planter will go there, and anything that can't will end up in the chest.

Answer (score 2):

Since the harvester can only really do vanilla crops, I used [autonomous activators](http://ftbwiki.org/Autonomous_Activator) on each of my lettuce plants with an itemduct connecting the output slots to a JABBA barrel.  You can choose whether the autonomous activators right or left click, so by having them right click you don't have to worry about replanting the lettuce seeds.  Yeah, it's expensive and takes up too much space, but it works pretty well seeing as harvesters aren't compatible.

Comment: Thanks, but I remembered on one of the YouTube video (know the [channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/BdoubleO100), not the video) that he successfully did it with tomatoes etc.  
Could it be something in the settings I could set?